# Include Drafts or Future posts with count_user_posts?

Tags: post-status

I'm use the code below to get the number of posts by a user and it works fine but it only includes published posts. How can I modify this code or use different code to have it include "future" post_status's or "drafts", for example.

```
<?php
$post_count = count_user_posts($curauth->ID);
echo '<p>User post count is ' . $post_count;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
$args = array(
    'author'      => $curauth->ID,
    'post_status' => array(
        'publish',
        'pending',
        'draft',
        'future'
    )
);
$posts = new WP_Query();

$post_count = $posts->found_posts;
```

It will include drafts, pending posts, published posts, and future posts. There are more you can set, such as trashed posts, and private posts, but that didn't seem to follow the intent of the question. This method will include custom post types as well as the builtin post types, so additional filtering may be in order.

Docs: [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Yeah. This is what I ended up doing that worked, based on what you said...


$num = $postcount_query->post_count; echo $num;

Comment: You probably want to use `found_posts`, post count can be affected by `posts_per_page`, which, while not used in this query, could present an issue down the line. Also, if you would, just tick the check under the answer so that anyone who comes by later can benefit from the knowledge you've gained.

Comment: You probably meant to write `$posts = new WP_Query( $args );` and not `$posts = new WP_Query();`, since `$args` otherwise will not be included. Commenting to help others.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via a custom query: Be sure to hook the query filter early enough.

*Note:* This solution doesn't help more than the answer from @m0r7if3r above as the query will be run *before* the filter.

```
function count_all_posts_by_user_cb( $count, $userid )
{
    global $wpdb;

    $where = $wpdb->prepare( 'WHERE post_author = %d AND post_type = %s AND ', $userid, $wpdb->posts )
    $where .= "(post_status = 'publish'";
    // for a full list, @see http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions
    foreach( array( 'private', 'draft', 'pending', 'future' ) as $status
        $where .= $wpdb->prepare( " OR post_status = '%s'", $status );
    $where .= ")";

    $result = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where" );

    return $result;
}
add_filter( 'get_usernumposts', 'count_all_posts_by_user_cb', 20, 2 );
```

*Note:* The filter will affect all calls to `count_user_posts();`. If you don't want that, then you'll have to check inside the filter cb fn, if the user has a specific role or ID or whatever restriction you need.